Share content of an iframe with other users
I am building a website using NodeJS that allows users to work together by using a simulation from PhET.
These simulations are embedded in the website within an iframe, and I would have multiple lobbies for a same simulation. When working together, only one user can interact with the simulation (let's call him the manipulator), while the others would simply watch (observators). With that being said, the observators would only need to see the content of the manipulator's iframe, just like a screen share but for a single iframe, and that's where I don't know how to proceed.
I've tried using getDisplayMedia() by croping the content with the iframe bounds, but this had 2 problems :

A popup shows up when the page loads and the manipulator has to accept sharing his screen, and after doing so, has a bar sitting at the top of the screen with a button to stop streaming, which I do not want him to be able to,
When the manipulator scrolls down the page, hiding the iframe, the observators cannot see the shared content neither

I've also thought about simply taking a "screenshot" of the iframe every X milliseconds (let's say 15 times a second) and send them to the appropriate lobby, but this approach is very resource-intensive as I have to create a canvas, draw the iframe's image into this canvas and send it to the observators for them to replace an img tag. I believe there's a better way to solve my issue.
I can also host the simulations on my server, if that helps, but I cannot change the source code and add event listeners or such, because I would like to make it so any simulation can be added very easily.
How can I make it so the observators see the content of the manipulator's iframe ? I would greatly appreciate any help.

I don't see how under these conditions, anything better than getDisplayMedia & related APIs, could come into play. Of course you won't be able to use them without the manipulator's consent - but that's just how it is; "snooping" technologies that would allow me to capture your screen content simply because you are "on" my website, without asking you for consent, simply must not exist - otherwise we all would be having massive privacy problems.

And regarding the second issue - don't use an iframe then, but an actual frameset?

I figured so, so I thought about proceeding differently, without streaming the manipulator's screen (even if only the iframe is streamed), but that's where I'm stuck and can't find any proper way to share an iframe's content from one user to other users. And regarding the frame and frameset tags, they are not recommended anymore as they have become obsolete.

"without streaming the manipulator's screen" - then their "manipulations" would have to be reported back to the simulation on your server somehow, so that the same actions could then be performed in the versions show to the observers - and if that functionality isn't already implemented by the simulation, and you don't want to add anything yourself either, that's not an option.

And regarding framesets being deprecated - use an iframe then, and emulate frameset behavior. One iframe and one div container, each taking full window height and half the width (or vice versa, and in whatever "ratio" you actually need) - and put all the scrollable content into the div container.

Did you have a look at the Element Capture API in Chrome browser? https://developer.chrome.com/docs/web-platform/element-capture

I did, but it has the same cons as getDisplayedMedia(), as it is simply an extension of it. I'm not sure I understood the part about iframe emulating a frameset behavior, wouldn't that still have the same issue as a simple iframe ? How would I share the content from the iframe/frameset to other users ?
